# Vertical Axis Scaling with JasperReport Charts

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, report

Is there a way to change the scalling of charts in JasperReports. The default is linear, however I would like to change it to a logarithmic. How would I go about doing this with a JasperReports (XY Bar Chart) chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a chart customizer to change the axis on the plot to a `LogarithmicAxis`. Something like the following:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
plot.setRangeAxis(new LogarithmicAxis("Log(y)"));
```